# Multiple choice excercise with more than one answer correct

Tags: complex-analysis, problem-solving, singularity, analytic-functions

> Q. Consider the function $$F(z)=\int_{1}^{2} \frac {1}{(x-z)^2}dx, {\text {Im}(z) \gt 0}$$
>   Then there is a meromorphic function function $G(z)$ on $\Bbb C$ that agrees with $F(z)$ when ${\text {Im}(z) \gt 0}$, such that
>
> A) $1,\infty$ are poles of $G(z)$.
>
> B) $0,1,\infty$ are poles of $G(z)$.
>
> C) $1,2$ are poles of $G(z)$.
>
> D) $1,2$ are simple poles of $G(z)$.

I solved the definite integral and got $F(z)=\frac {1}{(z-1)(z-2)}$. So options C & D are correct. But I am not able to think about $0$ and $\infty$ being the poles. In what direction should I think to solve this?

Thank you.